# Get files from FTP in ant

Tags: ant, ftp

I have a FTP folder structure as,

-- Folder 1

-- Folder 2

-- external

```
      -- Code
```

-- MY Dir

Now, I want to get the folder "Code" from here. I am using the code,

```
<ftp action="get"
           server="server"
           userid="administrator"
           password="pass" >
        <fileset dir="Code">
        </fileset>
      </ftp>
```

But this gets my whole contents present in the FTP rather than getting only the folder "Code".

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remote dir has to be used within the Ftp. The example is given below.

```
 <ftp action="get"
           server="sever"
           userid="user"
           password="pass"
            separator="/"
            remotedir="/remotedir">

        <fileset dir="e:/temp/">
            <include name="**/*" />
        </fileset>
      </ftp>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm using this and i t works for me http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-ftp-a-file-with-ant.html

edited: retrive files

```
<ftp    action="get"
        server="server"
        userid="administrator"
        password="pass">
    <fileset dir="/path/to/Code">
        <include name="*"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

Comment: Hello, The link which you had given is for "sending" the files.I want to retrieve the files from FTP.

Comment: Nope.. This doesn't work.... :-(
In the above case, I gave my dir in fileset as /external/code. But it doesnot return any folders or files from FTP.

Comment: try adding to ftp tag remotedir="/" or remotedir=""

Comment: Added the answer... Please check it.